# Unable to set NSNumber numberWithFloat

Tags: ios, objective-c, floating-accuracy, nsnumber

I am unable to set an attribute on an object like this:

```
NSLog(@"setting: %f", tempVal);
self.device.mainProperty.wanted = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:tempVal];
NSLog(@"set: %f", self.device.mainProperty.wanted.floatValue);
```

This gives me the following output:

```
2015-07-28 17:18:24.775 App[5488:1480266] setting: 4.500000
2015-07-28 17:18:24.775 App[5488:1480266] set: 4.000000
```

I am getting completely frustrated at this, it makes no sense to me. But perhaps someone can help me. Thanks

EDIT: 
I use this code for something where it only uses an integer. Then it works just fine.

Comment: Please provide the type of "wanted"?

Comment: Just tested in a new project, the code works fine. Can you provide more context? For example the declarations of `tempVal` and `self.device.mainProperty.wanted`? Try to reduce your code to a minimal example reproducing the issue.

Comment: Works fine for me too. Do you have a setter method for wanted, which handles incoming values and maybe modifies them?

Comment: I just realized, it could possibly be happening because wanted is a NSNumber from a Core Data datastore. Which might actually be an integer and not a float. That could possibly mess with this outcome. I will confirm this tomorrow when I get to work. Thank you all

Comment: check datatype of self.device.mainProperty.wanted .. It might be Integer like . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, me being a derp at the end of a long work day. I forgot the NSNumber 'wanted' was a Integer from a Core Data store. And apparently when you set the float for that attribute it will automatically convert it to an integer, even though I didn't save it to the datastore or anything. After a heavyweight data migration all was good. The more you know